# Admob doesn't work at my app for a certain time.

Tags: android, google-play, admob

1.On my new app (did not upload to play store yet) I see ads at the starting and then disappears all the ads. How can I figure out the problem?
2. In my existing app in play store adds doesn't work at night, mostly 11pm to morning. What can I do?

## Both apps are on the same adsense account.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your log. It will show ad request and response.
It sounds like there may be no ads available in your area. The logs will show that.
A way of mitigating is to use mediation so if no ad is available if asks the next ad network for an ad.